# Jquery acting strangely ? IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, error-handling

I am currently developing on my site [**safedealing.com**](http://www.safedealing.com). After I have done the last modifications of today, I was checking the website from the diffrent browsers. As I entered the site with **internet explorer 8**, I noticed the buttons weren't loading correctly.

After refreshing the page, I the button worked normaly. Then I refreshed the page again, and the button was acting odd again.

I thought it would be an error with the way I initialize my objects with jQuery. But I cannot see the error with it.

It looks following:

```
function InitializeFactors() {
/*
    I have all my initialize mechanisms here. This is a very long source
    However; I will show you an example from the source

        $('#login-incorrect-input').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: false,
            show: 'highlight',
            hide: 'highlight',
            width: 200,
            buttons: { 
                "OK": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    */
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    InitializeFactors();
});
```

**I suspect it is the $(document).ready that is working inproperly in IE8, but I am not sure? How could I fix this?**

Thanks in advance, Rasmus!

Comment: Which jQuery version? Try upgrading to 1.8.2.

Comment: It is 1.8.2, downloaded it an month ago.

Comment: Running your site in IE8 the following errors/warnings occur: `SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [type:"file"]` at `jquery-1.8.0.min.js, line 2 character 56619` and `SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.` The last warning `SEC7115` is something I might look into. Looks like your CSS is not acceptable to IE8. It also does this in IE9 compatible mode after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Can't accept your answer as it is an comment, however; I will look into it. I hope CSS is the trouble maker. But, why does it only act odd, sometimes?

Comment: @dotTutorials: I don't know if this is the reason for your issue exactly hence I would not deem it correct to be posted as an answer. Hope it helps though.

Comment: "It is 1.8.2, downloaded it an month ago". Unless you're a time traveler that's not possible since 1.8.2 was released two days ago.

Comment: My mistake. It is 1.8.something. Sorry :&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIXED**
My version of jQuery was at  1.8.1, after updating it to 1.8.2 it worked properly.
As suggested by `Fabrício Matté` in the comments on original post.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a `div` with `id="hiddendiv"`, that is initially hidden, and then do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hiddendiv').show();
});
```

that will display the `div`, so if it is visible you know if `document.ready` works

Comment: Updated jQuery to 1.8.2 - Mine was 1.8.1. That fixed the issue, however; thank you for your post. =)